# How do I connect Firebase Real-Time Database to my Angular 7 app? With CRUD operations

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angular7

I'm trying to connect my Real-Time Database to my Angular 7 application.
And I'm trying to code my Angular 7 app to be able to use the CRUD operations to update  the database.

I've added my Real-Time Database's API keys in the environment.ts file.

I'm not sure what are the codes (HTML,CRUD,Service.ts) to use.
(More of displaying the Homework List, Adding Homework and Deleting Homework)
Like what's the code to display,add,etc.

[This is my Project files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxHh6.png)

[image]

This is my crud.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList, AngularFireObject } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { User } from '../shared/user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class CrudService {
  usersRef: AngularFireList<any>;      // Reference to users list, Its an Observable
  userRef: AngularFireObject<any>;     // Reference to user object, Its an Observable too


  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }   // Inject AngularFireDatabase dependency in constructor


  // Create User
  AddUser(user: User) {
    this.usersRef.push({
      name: user.Name,
      Date: user.Date,
      CompletitionStatus: user.CompletionStatus
    })
  }

  // Read User
  GetUser(id: string) {
    this.userRef = this.db.object('users-list/' + id);
    return this.userRef;
  }

  // Read Users List
  GetUsersList() {
    this.usersRef = this.db.list('Homework');
    console.log(this.usersRef);
  }  

  // Update User
  UpdateUser(user: User) {
    this.userRef.update({
      name: user.Name,
      Date: user.Date,
      CompletitionStatus: user.CompletionStatus
    })
  }  

  // Delete User
  DeleteUser(id: string) { 
    this.userRef = this.db.object('users-list/'+id);
    this.userRef.remove();
  }

}
```

This is my user.ts:

```
export interface User {
    $key: string;
    Name: string;
    Date: string;
    CompletionStatus: string;
 }
```

Comment: Could you add your source code to question?

Comment: You can check this, 
https://debojyoti.dev/post/bbWU9hMjgKsjOJeKtQ4N

Comment: @HienNguyen Added!